# React Native unsubscribe.current is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react native and I'm trying to create a live search from cloud firestore using react hooks in react native. I'm facing issues in my home screen where I want to implement the live search

Comment: Also why are you escaping square brackets `\[\]`? There is no need to escape them, simply use `[]`.

Comment: Fixed, I think this was issue on the post only this is my first question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setState(data);` is causing the error. To set the value of any state variable

for eg. `data` in

```js
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

you need to call `setData(value);`